# Can I refactor this code in any way in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a 'render' function:

```
render: function(playerId){                                                         
    this.getTotalPoints(playerId);  
    // and some other code after this;                                                  
}
```

This 'render' function may be executed with or without a playerId. This is the getTotalPoints function:

```
getTotalPoints: function(playerId){
    if(playerId){
        this.allplayers[playerId].totalPoints = this.calculatePoints(this.allplayers[playerId].cards);
    }else{
        this.allplayers.forEach(function(element, index){                               
            element.totalPoints = this.calculatePoints(element.cards);
        }.bind(this));
    }                           
}
```

And the third function that actually calculates the points

```
calculatePoints: function(cards){                                       
    points = 0;

    for( var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){                             
        points+=cards[i].points;
    };

    return points;
}
```

I am repeating myself in `getTotalPoints`, where I have a call to `this.calculatePoints` - one for a single player and then one for all the players, depending on whether the `playerId` is set or not.

Is there any chance I can avoid this and simplify the code?

Comment: Please post to [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contains working code, and may be better suited on CodeReview instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
getTotalPoints: function(playerId){
    var selected = playerId ? [this.allplayers[playerId]] : this.allplayers;
    selected.forEach(function(element, index){                               
        element.totalPoints = this.calculatePoints(element.cards);
    }.bind(this));                  
}
```

However, since you're *changing the state* of the players, I would not call the function `getTotalPoints`, maybe `computeTotalPoints`?

Comment: I was actually doing this - var selected = playerId ? [this.allplayers[playerId]] : this.allplayers; but I was not wrapping this.allplayers[playerId] with [] and it was giving me an error. This works perfectly. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I see two different functions: `calculatePointsForPlayer` and `calculatePointsForPlayers`. Second function will call first function.